# How to write a deepMerge/deepClone function where the objects are actually copied?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Goal: copy two objects, completely
Problem: Using Object.assign doesn't do a deep copy

I wrote a deepMerge function following some examples I found here - and it doesn't seem to truly "clone" the objects. When I modify properties of the source, it modifies the target.

```
function isObject(item) {
  return (item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item));
}

function mergeDeep(target, source) {
  if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
      if (isObject(source[key])) {
        if (!(key in target)) {
          Object.assign(target, {
            [key]: source[key]
          });
        } else {
          mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);
        }
      } else {
        Object.assign(target, {
          [key]: source[key]
        });
      }
    })
  }
}

let target = {};
let source = {
    name: 'apple',
  items: [{
    id: '1',
    value: 'macintosh'
  }]
}

mergeDeep(target, source);
source.items[0].value = 'granny smith';
//expect target apple to still be 'macintosh'
alert(target.items[0].value); //prints 'granny smith'
```

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/q68z02pb/

Comment: `target[key] = mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);`? `mergeDeep` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Same result if I remove it.

Comment: if you don't want to import jQuery, maybe you can copy a part of it (link not tested, but jQuery extend works perfectly): https://gist.github.com/bentsai/3150936

Comment: Note - jQuery is not an option

Comment: (look at the link before saying that, i was just giving it to you in case you don't want to use jQuery, in the link is the vanilla code for extend function, not really vanilla but close enough) BTW i fear you will be forced to test the properties type at one point or another like in the link, to avoid passing by reference (reference value actually)

Comment: mergeDeep needs to return something (`target`) for that to work.  Also you only call mergeDeep recursively when you already have the property `key` in target.  That seems wrong, I don't see how that would ever trigger the recursive call.

Comment: What's the point of `if (!(key in target)) Object.assign(…)`? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign()` doesn't clone the references. For deep cloning you can use this technique `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source))`. So, your function may be like this:

```
function mergeDeep(target, source) {
   let sourceClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source));
   Object.assign(target, sourceClone);
}
```

Here is the modified sample https://jsfiddle.net/q68z02pb/3/